# How to compile h2.jar?

Tags: h2

I am trying to compile h2.jar. Getting following error - 
Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.4/servlet-api-2.4.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error downloading...

Any idea?

Thanks a lot,
Anuprit

Comment: Do you have an internet connection? If not, you need to install servlet-api-2.4.jar manually (download it and copy it to the ./ext/ directory).

Comment: Thomas, Amazing! It worked like a charm. I have internet connection but somehow it was not able to connect. I had downloaded the jars and added them to classpath. But it was not able to find them. When I copied them ./ext h2 got compiled. Thanks. :)